# create activeresource model factory using Factory Bot in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, activeresource

How to create rspec factory of activeresource model?

Answer (score 1):

You can create factories for activeresource models just like activerecord models. For example, here is a model and corresponding factory

```
class Person < ActiveResource::Base
  self.site = "http://api.people.com:3000"
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :person do
    name { "test" }
  end
end
```

Note: every time you create a factory (e.g. `FactoryBot.create(:person)`), you will make an API request. You may want to mock out API requests when testing. Here is an example of how to use [activeresource's http mocking](https://github.com/rails/activeresource/blob/eb198c84ca6be099d94c13f22d4d1fad7ddb620f/test/cases/base/custom_methods_test.rb)